# Ошибка 302 при попытке получения списка подписчиков и подписок

Tags: delphi, instagram, synapse

Использую синапс. Авторизуюсь нормально. Получаю токены. Хочу получить список моих подписчиков и подписок. `http.HTTPMethod('GET','https://www.instagram.com/мой_логин/followers/');` в ответе получаю ошибку 302. Как я понимаю редирект. Но что самое обидное `Location: https://www.instagram.com/мой_логин/` перенаправить он меня хочет просто на мою страницу. Подскажите, кто что может?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте версию протокола указать
`SynHttp.Protocol := '1.1';`

Comment: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://www.instagram.com/мой_логин/

Comment: Немного поняла, но проблему не решила. Получается что если обращаться к этому адресу https://www.instagram.com/мой _логин/followers/  даже через браузер, снифер возращает ошибку 302 . Тогда вопрос, а куда нужно обращаться?